# I'm getting a TS2639 error using typeof to identify the type of an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to check the type of an object before further processing the data. To start, the interfaces I'm working with look like this

```
export interface GraphicElement {
    element: string;
    elementId: string;
    selfClosing?: boolean;
    bind?: string;
    value?: string;
    properties: GraphicProperties;
    responsiveProperties?: ResponsiveProperties;
}

export interface GraphicGroupElement {
    groupId: string;
    element: string;
    objects: Array<GraphicGroupElement | GraphicElement>;
    coreProperties?: GraphicProperties;
}
```

I'm iterating over the `objects` property in the `GraphicGroupElement` objects with a `forEach()` method and attempting to check the type of the object before further processing the data.  So far my function looks like this

```
private generateGraphicGroup(data: GraphicGroupElement) {
    let groupScript: string[] = [];
    groupScript.push(`<${data.element} id="${data.groupId}">`);

    data.objects.forEach((a:GraphicGroupElement | GraphicElement) => {
        const typeChecker: boolean = (typeof a === GraphicGroupElement ? true : false);
        //stopped coding here.
    });
}
```

I haven't gone any farther with the rest of the function yet because I'm getting the "TS2639" error and want to figure out what I need to do before proceeding. It says I'm using `GraphicGroupElement` as a value in this instance when it refers to a type.

I tried changing it to `typeof a === 'GraphicGroupELement'` but got another error saying the condition would always result as false because there's no overlap between that and a list of other types.

What's causing this to happen? What do I need to do to successfully check the types of each object?

Comment: Instead of using interface, define a class for the object and use `instanceof` instead of `typeof`.

Comment: Interfaces don't exist at runtime. They only exist at compilation time. So there's no way to check if an object is an instance of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is no interfaces at runtime, it's only a compile time type constraint. But, you can create a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) function to check, is an item is a group or not, for example:

```js
function isGraphicGroupElement(element: GraphicElement | GraphicGroupElement): element is GraphicGroupElement {
    return (element as GraphicGroupElement).groupId !== undefined;
}

...

if (isGraphicGroupElement(element)) {
    // is a group
} else {
    // is a element
}
```

Another solution might be to use classes instead of interfaces, in this case you can use `instanceof` operator to check an object type. Like:

```js
class GraphicElement { ... }

...

if (element instanceof GraphicElement) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `in` operator: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator

```js
private generateGraphicGroup(data: GraphicGroupElement) {
    let groupScript: string[] = [];
    groupScript.push(`<${data.element} id="${data.groupId}">`);

    data.objects.forEach((a:GraphicGroupElement | GraphicElement) => {
        if ('groupId' in a) {
           // a is GraphicGroupElement 
        } else {
           // a is GraphicElement
        }
    });
}
```